# Server static assets using a DNS subpath from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have setup an EKS cluster v1.28 using terraform to host a web solution,3 apis and 2 react fronts.
The cluster's DNS is manged via [External-DNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) with a DNS that we will call `example.com`.
I' managing Loadbalancing via [aws loadbalancer controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.6/)

I'm referencing all my static assets in my react frontend application with `/resources`, to this day all static assets are served from my nginx container and stored mostly in a s3 bucket.

The problem is that these resources are doing more hops than it should be and generate more billable traffic,

The current flow: S3 -> container (nginx) -> LB (ALB) -> browser

Target: S3 (or cloudfront) -> browser

My Question:
Is it possible to route `dev.front.example.com/resources` to load assets directely from s3 or cloufront, I want to keep the dns managed via external-dns

---

**EDIT**: Nginx configuration:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  nginx-dev.conf: |
    server {
      listen 80;

      location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
      }

      location /api/ {
          proxy_pass https://dev.api.admin.example.com/;
      }
    
      location /resources/ {
          proxy_pass https://bucket-dev.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/;
      }

    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: b2b-front-configs
```

In my pod config I mounted the config above as volume.

```
volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
          subPath: default.conf
  nodeSelector:
    instance-type: work-load
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-config
      configMap:
        name: b2b-front-configs
        items:
          - key: nginx-dev.conf
            path: default.conf
```

Comment: Could you show evidence / output of the resources doing more hops than it should?

Comment: the nginx config I'm usin is  implemented via a a proxy pass to re-route all the traffic to s3 bucket